# Extract e-mail with a certain domain from a semicolon-separated vector of e-mails

Tags: r, regex

Consider the following vector of e-mails:

```
emails <- c("blah@my.blah.com;etc@etc.edu;me@me.gov",
            "yay@something.gov;yes@my.blah.com;maybe@maybe.net",
            "someemail@nothing.gov")
```

Each element of the vector above is a semi-colon separated string of e-mail address for a user. In this case, for example, the first user has three e-mails: `blah@my.blah.com`, `etc@etc.edu`, and `me@me.gov`.

I have  a specific domain name I am interested in - let's say it's `my.blah.com`. I also know for a fact that, given my domain knowledge of this problem, that each user can only have one `my.blah.com` e-mail address, if it exists. I would like to return this e-mail address for each user as a character vector, and return `NA` in the cases in which a `my.blah.com` e-mail address does not exist.

Thus, the output should be

```
c("blah@my.blah.com", "yes@my.blah.com", NA)
```

My best attempt at this is

```
emails <- c("blah@my.blah.com;etc@etc.edu;me@me.gov",
            "yay@something.gov;yes@my.blah.com;maybe@maybe.net",
            "someemail@nothing.gov")

regmatches(emails,
           regexec("+.*@my.blah.com", 
                   emails))

[[1]]
[1] "blah@my.blah.com"

[[2]]
[1] "yay@something.gov;yes@my.blah.com"

[[3]]
character(0)
```

which isn't a character vector, but I'm struggling to just get the RegEx right at this point, which is what I'd like to focus on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could split the strings on `";"` and then use `grep` with the `pattern` ending with `"my.blah.com"` and return `value` for those matching.

```
sapply(strsplit(emails, ";"), grep, pattern = "@my\\.blah\\.com$", value = TRUE)

#[[1]]
#[1] "blah@my.blah.com"

#[[2]]
#[1] "yes@my.blah.com"

#[[3]]
#character(0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one approach using `regmatches`, along the lines of what you were trying to do:

```
emails <- c("blah@my.blah.com;etc@etc.edu;me@me.gov",
            "yay@something.gov;yes@my.blah.com;maybe@maybe.net;stuff@my.blah.com",
            "someemail@nothing.gov")

sapply(emails, function(x) {
    m <- gregexpr("[^;]+@my\\.blah\\.com", x)
    regmatches(x, m)
})
names(matches) <- seq(1:length(matches))
matches

$`1`
[1] "blah@my.blah.com"

$`2`
[1] "yes@my.blah.com"   "stuff@my.blah.com"

$`3`
character(0)
```

Answer (score 2):

An option with `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(emails, "\\w+@my\\.blah\\.com")
#[[1]]
#[1] "blah@my.blah.com"

#[[2]]
#[1] "yes@my.blah.com"   "stuff@my.blah.com"

#[[3]]
#character(0)
```

---

If we need only one email address

```
str_extract(emails, "\\w+@my\\.blah\\.com")
#[1] "blah@my.blah.com" "yes@my.blah.com"  NA
```